# How to find the number of bytes dropped on an interface?

Tags: interface, ifconfig

I wanted to collect statistics for a network interface. I have found that `ifconfig` has bytes sent/received, packets dropped, errors, etc and so does `cat /proc/net/dev`.

Is there a way to get the number of ***bytes*** dropped by the interface?

Thanks!

Comment: "You can't. Packets can be of different sizes, so there's no single mapping from 'number of packets' to 'number of bytes'." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239648/how-can-i-convert-from-packets-to-bytes

Comment: @AndroidDev This is the answer. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @heemayl -  Done

Comment: Thanks @Taft for the correction. 

I was actually looking to get the no of dropped packets directly using some command or a proc file rather than using the number of packets droped. One way to do this would be to modify the kernel to store the size of packets before dropping and output that information using proc files. 

I am really looking for something simpler than this.

Comment: You are welcome @FloyedLobo.  I think some of the stats maybe more hardware NIC behaviour than kernel but that is only a vague feeling.  Sorry I cannot provide an answer. The only way I have done something similar is using Cacti and monitoring the managed switch a port is connected to.  You have to piece it together based on how much data is going in and out of the whole switch but you can see packet loss rates at least. Munin will record the packet loss per second a on a port, but not the size of the data lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple answer:** You can't.

---

**Technical answer:**

> Packets can be of different sizes, so there's no single
>   mapping from "number of packets" to "number of bytes".

`/proc/net/dev` and all commands read from that file (e.g. `ifconfig`) only give the number of dropped packets, not the number of bytes.

---

Source: [this answer regarding C# implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20239712/6192153) on Stack Overflow by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)